# Change the flex direction of only some flex items

Tags: css, flexbox

Without changing the html structure, is it possible to display the last 2 divs on the same line (row direction)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elt1">elt1</div>
  <div class="elt2">elt2</div>
  <div class="elt3">elt3</div>
  <div class="elt4">elt4 to be in row</div>
  <div class="elt5">elt5 to be in row</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you use `flex-wrap: wrap;` and the default `flex-direction: row` plus 100%/50% `width` settings on the children as follows:

(edited: additional centering of content as asked for in the comments)

```css
.wrapper {
  display :flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
.wrapper > * {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper > *:last-child,
.wrapper > *:nth-last-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elt1">elt1</div>
  <div class="elt2">elt2</div>
  <div class="elt3">elt3</div>
  <div class="elt4">elt4 to be in row</div>
  <div class="elt5">elt5 to be in row</div>
</div>
```

Comment: good but my property  .wrapper { align-items: center; } does not work anymore. is there a way to keep it working ?

Comment: You can add `text-align: center;` to the children , or apply `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center` to the flex items  (which I just edited in my answer's snippet) .